# can't bind list to ngModel

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let detaile of itemlist">
        <td>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">

                    <div class=" d-inline-block">
                    {{detaile.SizeID}}
                    {{detaile.Size}}
                    {{detaile.Price}}
                    <select class="custom-select   form-control" id="detaile.SizeID"  [(ngModel)]="detaile.SizeID" (change)="selectedSizeHandler($event)" name="sizeItem1"   >
                        {{detaile.SizeID}}
                        <option value="0">Choose Size</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let size of sizes" [value]="size.ID">{{size.Name}}</option>
                    </select> 
                    <!-- <input type="text" [value]="detaile.SizeID"> -->
                </div> 
                    <div  class=" d-inline-block">

                    <input type="number" id="detaile.SizeID" [(ngModel)]="detaile.Price" name="picee" class=" form-control" name="price11" min="0"  placeholder="Price"  />
                </div> 
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>

</tbody>
```

When trying to bind the itemList to set each dropdownlist item, it only set the last object in the ngModel to all dropdownlist

Comment: your code work, see the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hq34dz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html So the problem must be in the function selectedSizeHandler. BTW,In Angular and ngModel,  I prefer use [ngModel] (ngModelChange) better than (change): `<select [ngModel]="detaile.SizeID"  (ngModelChange)="detaile.SizeID=$event;selectedSizeHandler($event)"   >`

Comment: Thank You, I fixed the problem